# search the product by tag or category not working

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am working on a search. I am trying to search the product by tag or category. I tried the below code but it's not working. I am getting

> Nothing Found

Also, the Below code is working only with title and content.

Would you help me out with this?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * @package CoolPickings
 */

get_header();
?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area mainSearch">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
            <div class="equalPadding">
                <div class="cp-seeWrapper">
        <?php 

                    if ( have_posts() ) : 
                    ?>
           <div class="row">
            <?php   

       while (have_posts()){the_post();?>
         <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="cp-shadow cp-seeSinglePostWrapper">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    <div class="bg-white single-post-box">
                    <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
                     <div class="seeDate"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></div>
                        <div class="cp_cat_list">
                            <?php $cat = get_the_category();
                            ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $cat[0]->term_id ) );?>"><?php echo $cat[0]->cat_name?></a><?php //the_category(''); 

                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="cp-b-content"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 12, '...'); ?></a></h2></div>
                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 25, '...'); ?></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
             <?php } ?>

            <?php //endwhile;

            //the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this goes on the WordPress stack exchange

Comment: @TomJNowell, I have to different question. Here I am asking for tag and category.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code below. The only difference is using `terms` as an array.

```php
$getSearch=get_search_query();
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($getSearch) // Using the terms as an array
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($getSearch) // Using the terms as an array
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// ... functions.php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_exclude' );

function my_search_exclude( $query ) 
{
    if ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 's', '' );
    }
}
```

You can find more info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: Please check the variable `$getSearch` what is it's returning and make sure you have that tag or category exist.

Comment: I enter the "Test" in the search field. Then I  print($getSearch) I got my output. Now "Test" is a tag that is already added to one of my product.

Comment: Okay, you're not searching with the name. Your search is with slug. In this case, the tag Test slug will be test. Otherwise, change the value of `field` to 'name' like this `'field' => 'name'`.

Comment: I tried title and content as well that also not working

Comment: Is it a product exist for the Test tag?

Comment: Yes, check this tag here https://prnt.sc/q9qf4d   and i tried test also but still same issue. I change the     'post_type' => 'product' to     'post_type' => 'post'   Search result https://prnt.sc/q9qgmw

Comment: any more help in this?

Comment: I would suggest 2 options:
1. Alter your search query, you can find more information about it here https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/
2. You can use custom page template instead of `search.php` and try with the above query args. Maybe it will work.

Comment: I created search.php page. and added my above code. Before I was using this code https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/353833/search-the-record-by-tag-or-category-without-plugin and it was working with title and content but now i have to search with tag.

Comment: Try to alter your search query by setting `$query-> set('s' , '');` and see.

Comment: I added before new WP_Query( $args ) and I got error  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set() on null in

Comment: Check this following post, maybe will be helpful.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/

Comment: I tried your updated code  error gone. but nothing is happening in search. I updated my code in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204125/discussion-between-shifrin-and-naren-verma).

Comment: This question only lets you search for exact slug names, which I believe is the confusion here. It also assumes a standard post loop, but a question by the same author on the WP stack and the comments, indicates this is not true

Comment: @TomJNowell, so it is not possible with WP_Query. right? so what is the other way?

Comment: @NarenVerma in all honesty I would ask a brand new question on the WP Stack: "How do I search post title, content, and term names?", your current questions are crippled because instead of asking about your problem, you're asking how to fix your solution. There is no way to fix the code in your question. Revert back to a normal `search.php` search template then ask how to make it search categories

Comment: @TomJNowell, I deleted old code and added back to normal search code in the question.